# IF statements SharePoint 2003

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am using SharePoint 2003.

Only 7 If statements on SharePoint:

- 1,2,3 < green
- 4,5,6 yellow
- 8,9,10 amber
- 15 > red

```
=IF(RAG<=3,"Green",IF(RAG=4,"Yellow",IF(RAG=5,"Yellow",IF(RAG=6,"Yellow",IF(RAG=8,"Amber",IF(RAG=12,"Amber",IF(RAG>=15,"Red")))))))
```

Comment: What's the exact problem here? Is it throwing an error or is it not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[RAG]` column is of type *Number*, try using this:

```
=IF([RAG] <= 3, "Green", IF(OR([RAG] = 4, [RAG] = 5, [RAG] = 6), "Yellow", IF(OR([RAG] = 8, [RAG] = 9, [RAG] = 10), "Amber", IF([RAG] >= 15, "Red", ""))))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Adjust `[RAG] >= 15` condition as per your requirements. either `[RAG] >= 15` OR `[RAG] > 15`.

Comment: Thank you so much I tried all day